# Android resource linking failed (build gradle error)

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, version

So, I've been upgrading my sdk and updating my jdk, moving a lot of stuff because there was not compatibility between my projects and external libraries, at the end of the day, I could open those libraries, but now my project does not load and get this message

[image]
I've been told that the problem may be in the build gradle settings, I have made some changes there, and it was supposed to Android Studio notify me about this errors but apparently there is no such a thing, but still the project does not work

Any ideas of how can I get track of the error?

Comment: Add full log cat error. I think your anyone XML code have wrong code.

Comment: may be u using removed resources or haven't had resource name in ur XML file.